# Trying to generate random text in Java - "Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int"

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate 100 characters of random text in Java. Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class RandomTextGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int a = Math.round(62*Math.random());
        int b = a + 1;
        System.out.println(characters.substring(a,b));
    }
}
```

I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int".

But I don't understand this. I clearly declared `a` and `b` as `int`, not `long`. I'm expecting my code to give me a random integer from 0 to 61 so it shouldn't automatically be a `long` because 0 and 61 are well within the range of integers.

I am fairly new to Java so apologies if I'm doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: `Math.random` returns a  `double` so therefore the overload of `Math.round` returning a `long` is used. And because your variables are smaller you get the error

Comment: change `int A` and `int B` to `long A` and `long B` and you should be fine

Comment: I already tried replacing int A and int B with long A and long B, it didn't work because .substring() expects ints.

Comment: I think I now understand what caused the problem. Thanks, UnholySheep! How do I fix it, though?

Comment: By the way, Java naming conventions say variable names should be lowercase, `a` & `b`. More readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.round() is returning long here, so you can type cast it by writing like this,

```
int A = (int) Math.round(62*Math.random());
```

Another way of doing this is (but inefficient)

```
int A = Long.valueOf(Math.round(62*Math.random())).intValue();
```

Rest you are doing it right. :)

This is kind of downcasting it (loss of information can happen), so you need to be sure that the number on the right side is within the range of int only.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using class [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) to generate random `int`s.

```java
String characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int a = rand.nextInt(62);
    int b = a + 1;
    System.out.println(characters.substring(a,b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mixing types impacts your results

You said:

> I'm expecting my code to give me a random integer from 0 to 61

Your expectation is incorrect.

First you mix types in within these parentheses: `(62*Math.random())`. On the left is an `int`, as inferred by the compiler. (See the Java Language Specification [about literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10).) On the right is a call to [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()), which is documented as returning a `double`. What happens when you multiply an `int` by a `double` in Java? The result is a `double`.

Then you pass that `double` value in your call to `Math.round`. [Study the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html). You will find *two* methods named `round`, each taking a different type of parameter. And **each returns a different type**. The method [`Math.round(double a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) returns a `long`, while the other [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) returns an `int`.

You would have avoided this trickery by **keeping your code utterly simple** rather than nesting operations within a line of code. You would incrementally declare each stage in the calculation, making you quite aware of the data type of each return value. Step-by-step results makes your debugging easier. And, as a bonus, simple code is more likely to be highly optimized by the compiler.

Also, you can call `Math.toIntExact` to convert a `long` to an `int` when you are sure the value will fit. This method throws an exception if the value overflows an `int`. So you will be alerted if your expectation of fitting proves incorrect.

Also, your code will be much easier to comprehend if you avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Use well-named variables/[constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) instead. For example, I did not immediately understand your `62` multiplicand is the length of your pool of characters. And another point: Such a number should be [soft-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding) with a call to [`String#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()).

One more problem: Your code breaks if the starting position on the pool happens to be the last character in the pool. Then adding one takes you past the end, resulting in a runtime error. So subtract one from your limit of `62`, to get `61`. Or in code below, `( POOL_OF_CHARACTERS.length() - 1 )`.

Pulling that all together, you may get code like this:

```java
final String POOL_OF_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
final int DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT = 100;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( "" );
for ( int i = 0 ; i < DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT ; i++ )
{
    double randomProduct = ( ( POOL_OF_CHARACTERS.length() - 1 ) * Math.random() );
    long intermediateResult = Math.round( randomProduct );
    int startingPositionInPool = Math.toIntExact( intermediateResult ); // Throws an exception if the value overflows an int.
    int endingPositionInPool = ( startingPositionInPool + 1 );
    String piece = POOL_OF_CHARACTERS.substring( startingPositionInPool , endingPositionInPool );
    stringBuilder.append( piece );
}
String randomString = stringBuilder.toString();
System.out.println( "randomString = " + randomString );
```

When run.

> randomString = 7YqRnJ4TXzMo3nvoUkBRQYq5evOhBjo3I2Cc9fTWAfCFlGY5R4rlFjWqqwRqERkVylXI7le4VLs5nKBHlNuHb03qxFeebDBSsHab

By the way, I would replace `Math.random` with the more convenient [`ThreadLocalRandom#nextInt( int origin , int bound )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)). Notice how that method is Half-Open, with the beginning being *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So we will not have a problem with going beyond the end of the pool. We do not need to subtract one.

```java
final String POOL_OF_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
final int DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT = 100;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( "" );
for ( int i = 0 ; i < DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT ; i++ )
{
    int startingPositionInPool = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , POOL_OF_CHARACTERS.length() );  // Half-Open. The specified bound is exclusive.
    int endingPositionInPool = ( startingPositionInPool + 1 );  
    String piece = POOL_OF_CHARACTERS.substring( startingPositionInPool , endingPositionInPool );
    stringBuilder.append( piece );
}
String randomString = stringBuilder.toString();
System.out.println( "randomString = " + randomString );
```

---

By the way, just for fun, here is an entirely different way to accomplish the same result. This approach uses [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html), and [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). (Not necessarily better though, in this case.)

```java
final long DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT = 100;
int[] poolOfCodePoints = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".codePoints().toArray();
IntStream positions = new Random().ints( DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT , 0 , poolOfCodePoints.length );
IntStream codePoints = positions.map( indexIntoCodePoints -> poolOfCodePoints[ indexIntoCodePoints ] );
StringBuilder stringBuilder = codePoints.collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append );
String randomText = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Or, shorter:

```java
final long DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT = 100;
int[] poolOfCodePoints = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".codePoints().toArray();
String randomText =
        new Random()
                .ints( DESIRED_LENGTH_OF_RESULTING_TEXT , 0 , poolOfCodePoints.length )
                .map( indexIntoCodePoints -> poolOfCodePoints[ indexIntoCodePoints ] )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```